# Can't get rid of PHP 5.4.4

Tags: php

I recently upgraded from PHP 5.3.4 to PHP 5.4.4, and now I want to downgrade. I removed all the packages through `apt-get remove php5` after removing the repository, and then ran `apt-get install php5` but still, Apache can't start now and the error log shows:

```
[Thu Aug 23 19:01:10 2012] [notice] Apache/2.2.17 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.4.4-4~natty+1 configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I even ran this to make sure there is no more 5.4.4:

```
root@server:~# apt-cache policy php5
php5:
  Installed: 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10
  Candidate: 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10
  Version table:
 *** 5.3.5-1ubuntu7.10 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.3.5-1ubuntu7 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ natty/main i386 Packages
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You might get better answers on Serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

when you did `apt-get remove php5` you have just removed the meta-package.

To list all php5 packages you have installed you need to do: `dpkg -l '*php5*'` and then remove all installed, or just do `apt-get remove php5-common`, which will remove "base" package which is the dependency of all other php5 packages in the dependency chain and thus remove all installed php5 packages.

Cheers,
Ondrej

Answer (score 0):

"Apache should be looking for modules in "/usr/libexec/httpd/". In there you'll find either a file or symlink called "libphp5.so". If it's a symlink, you'll need to relink to the new 5.2.8 libphp5.so, otherwise just copy the 5.2.8 libphp5.so to "/usr/libexec/httpd/" and restart apache with "sudo apachectl restart"."

Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387992/how-do-i-tell-apache-which-php-to-use

Comment: Can't find the directory `/usr/libexec`.

Answer (score -2):

You could try

```
sudo apt-get purge php5-*
```